# Firing an event for Journey inject via API throwing Fuel and HubApp errors

Tags: rest-api, fuel-sdk, event, journeybuilder, fuel

I created an App Center app a week ago so that I could make REST API calls to a Marketing Cloud account and trigger Journeys. I then created, and tested a proof of concept Journey. It worked as expected.

However, this week, when I make the same call to the same Journey, I'm getting errors. The REST call returns an instance Id which implies the call was successfully made. The data entry source for the Journey is, in fact, being populated. The contact is injected into the Journey. However, it just hangs at the first wait period.

Trying a different journey, the REST call is successful, the contact is inserted into the data source entry DE but is never injected into the journey.

I've tried deleting and creating a new POC data source entry, contact event, and Journey. But the result is the same. I've also deleted the App Center apps and created new ones. But again, the result is the same.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas why this may be happening and what I might try to resolve the problem?

New Error ID:654805764Error Date:11/1/2015 11:36:19 AMError Code ID:0Account
ID:7210333User ID:0Enterprise ID:7208731DB ID:733Description:

Error adding value to cache with cacheName FuelClientIdAppIdMap and
cacheKey 2cc60f5d-9fd0-4ffe-b374-0d8c09dd122a

Exception Detail:

Error adding value to cache with cacheName FuelClientIdAppIdMap and
cacheKey 2cc60f5d-9fd0-4ffe-b374-0d8c09dd122a

Server:ATL1S07HUSVC15Application:/HubServiceAssembly:ExactTarget.Core,
Version=151.7.0.91, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3ca85e74a7e49d9Is
Event:False

and

Error ID: 2904296823New Error ID:168123637Error Date:11/1/2015 10:51:00 AMError
Code ID:0Account ID:7210333User ID:0Enterprise ID:7208731DB ID:733
Description:

[E218]:An exception occured while initlizing datasourcesettings for MID 7210333

Exception Detail:

ExactTarget.Integration.Member.AlternateKeyStore.Salesforce.SfAlternateKeyStoreException:
[E218]:An exception occured while initlizing datasourcesettings for
MID 7210333 --->
ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SalesforceLoginException: Username
is missing for MemberID: 7210333
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SfCredentialProviderAdminWithBUSupport.LoadSFCredentials(String&
Username, String& Password)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SfSessionEntryFactory.GetSessionEntry(Boolean
RunAsAdmin, ETPrincipal Principal)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SFSessionCache.GetSFSession(ETPrincipal
principal, Boolean UseAdminAcct)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SFObject.GetSFService(ETPrincipal&
principal, Boolean useAdminAcct, SFEnvironment sfenv)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Salesforce.SFObject.GetUserInfo(ETPrincipal
principal, Boolean useAdminAcct, SFEnvironment sfEnv, SforceService
CustomService)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Member.AlternateKeyStore.Salesforce.SalesforceDataSourceSettings.PopulatePatternValuesForPatternStrings(List`1
patternStrings)
at ExactTarget.Integration.Member.AlternateKeyStore.Salesforce.SalesforceDataSourceSettings..ctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server:XTGAP4RMMPP04Application:ProcessPipelineService.exeAssembly:ExactTarget.Core,
Version=151.7.0.91, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3ca85e74a7e49d9Request
ID:04a16200-cc51-4e03-8a8f-93ba19f54a74Exception Type:
ExactTarget.Integration.Member.AlternateKeyStore.Salesforce.SfAlternateKeyStoreExceptionIs
Event:False